# In how many ways $10$ people can sleep in two rooms?

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many ways $10$ people can sleep in two rooms?

I have tried to solve this in the following way:
As there are $10$ people and $2$ rooms so they can sleep in $10C2$ ways.
But the book says $1024$ ways or $2^{10}$ ways.
How is this possible?

Comment: Start with a simpler case, say 3 people A, B, C. You can easily write down the possibilities. And try to see what is happening. (I'm just helping you to solve this on your own)

Comment: Each person has two choices.

Comment: Notice that $\binom{10}{2} = \frac{10!}{2!8!}$ is the number of ways of selecting a subset of two of the ten people, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The book answer assumes the rooms are distinct, so each person chooses one of the $2$ rooms and there are $2^{10}$ ways they can choose.  Your answer chooses two people to sleep in one room, but there is no reason to think they split $2$ and $8$.  If the two rooms are interchangeable, it would be $2^9$ because person $1$ determines which room is which.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the problem like this:  You have a 10 bit binary number, with each position equal to a particular person.  Label the first room "Room 0" and the second room "Room 1.".  You can have an example arrangement like this:
0010011001

which means that the first two people are in room 0, the third is in room 1, etc.  There are $2^{10}$ such patterns.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

For each person there are two ways in which he can sleep in one of the room.$$ $$
It is a case of total number of function from A to B where set A has 10 people and set B has 2 rooms.$$ $$
Number of ways is $2^{10}$

Comment: You are violating site quality standards. Please read [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).  Please, instead, help the OP to improve their very low quality question.